# setTimeout never calls when exception is thrown in different context

Tags: node.js, settimeout

Using node.js, when I run the program

```
setTimeout(() => console.log("Timed out"), 0);
console.log("finishing");
```

I see

```
finishing
Timed out
```

But when I add a throw before "finishing"

```
setTimeout(() => console.log("Timed out"), 0);
throw new Error();
console.log("finishing");
```

I see

```
throw new Error();
^

Error
    at Object.<anonymous> ...(stack trace here)...
```

And I don't see any mention of "Timed out".

Why is that? Even though the initial context would throw, once the stack was freed up, I expected the callback I passed to setTimeout would still run.

Does having an uncaught exception cause all timeouts to get canceled? Is this feature documented somewhere?

If I have multiple timeouts, is there a way for me to make sure that all the other timeouts continue to run when they can even if one of them happens to throw?

Comment: When there is an unhandled exception in your code, your program aborts.

Comment: Which browser did you test with? Both, Firefox and Chrome, *do* log `Timed Out`.

Comment: @str I haven't tested on any browsers, but I would've expected all browsers to respect setTimeout. The issue is that when you run it on node.js it doesn't work the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike a web application running on browser, a Node application runs as a process on top of Google V8 JavaScript Engine. If you look into https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html is states that

> The timer functions within Node.js implement a similar API as the timers API provided by Web Browsers but use a different internal implementation that is built around the Node.js Event Loop.

As the above statement explains, even though the same global functions are available in both cases, their implementations are different. Therefore when an uncaught exception occurs in a Node application, all code related to timeouts will stop as the process is terminated. The best way to handle this is to properly handle all exceptions. You can use the below code to capture all uncaught exceptions from the process level itself.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: :') great. you may comment now